# Storing data's of different data types in an array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to store user input which consists of different data types. I need to store them in an array in a specific format.. For example if user enters 
**hai 1994** 
in a text box, the data 
**hai 1994** 
should be stored in an array like 
**arr=['hai', 1994]**

Done so far:

**home_controller.rb :**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index

    @data = params[:text1]

  end

end
```

---

**index.html.erb:**

```
<form action = "/home/index" >
   Please enter some data
   <br>
   <textarea name="text1"  cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: ...and what have you got so far?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I will modify my question with so far what i have tried. please wait

Comment: can any one give the code for identifying all types of data and storing it in a specific format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just parse it to get the various pieces, then iterate over it. I'm assuming that you'll only be dealing with strings and integers:

```
def index
  @data1 = params[:text1].split(" ").map do |entry|
    if entry.to_i == 0 && entry != "0" # this is a string so leave it
      entry
    else
      entry.to_i
    end
  end
end
```

That would take your input of "HAI 1994" and return the array `["HAI", 1994]`.

Comment: user input can be of any data type such as string, text, date and time, fixnum

Comment: In that case you need to do much more checking and format matching. You could extend the if statement block I've given as an example to identify all the different types you're trying to identify.

Comment: can you write the complete code for all data types ?

Comment: Thank you Ross. I'm able to store it. But I don't how to identify and store data and time, float, text. Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution for Your Question

program :-

```
class Program

  def method(a)

    b = []

    for i in 0..a-1

      puts "enter a value"

      b << gets.chomp.split(' ') # split the given string when it find a space between them

    end


    for j in 0..a-1

      print  "#{b} "
    end

  end

end

obj = Program.new

puts "how many values you want to enter "

k = gets.chomp

obj.method(k.to_i)
```

output :

```
how many values you want to enter 

1

enter a value

1991 madhu

[["1991", "madhu"]]
```

Comment: 1991 should be stored as integer and madhu should be stored as string     Eg: [1991, "madhu"]